# FFMPEG: only get audio compressed frames / packets. command line

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, compression, frames

I would like a command like for FFMPEG that will create a file which contains only uncompressed audio frames/packets from a file.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 --no-decompress out
```

Something like this would be fantastic.

Comment: Requests for cmd-line options to utilities don't qualify as programming Qs. Please use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move to http://superuser.com . Good luck.

Comment: So you want MP3 without the header?

Comment: basically, i want individual frames that I can send in a TCP packet